# Create new column with sum of vector column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[[1,2,3],[4,5,6,7],[8,9]]})
```

All entries are integers.

I want to make a make a new column, 'B', that would read `[5,22,17]`.

I can do this with a loop, but is there a one-line solution? Thanks!

Comment: This is _not_ a good use-case for pandas. Why do you want a df in the first place? Storing Python objects (e.g. lists) in a column just collapses any benefit of pandas

Comment: @roganjosh this is one of many columns in my real df

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check with re-construct your list columns , then do `sum`

```
pd.DataFrame(df.A.tolist()).sum(1)
0     6.0
1    22.0
2    17.0
dtype: float64
df['New']=pd.DataFrame(df.A.tolist()).sum(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

To extract the rows from your DataFrame and sum each row as a builtin python list:

```
res = [sum(x[0]) for x in df.values.tolist()]
res
[6, 22, 17]
```

To assign the row sums into a new column:

```
df['B'] = [sum(x[0]) for x in df.values.tolist()]
df
              A   B
0     [1, 2, 3]   6
1  [4, 5, 6, 7]  22
2        [8, 9]  17
```

As @roganjosh commented, try to avoid storing builtin python objects like lists in pandas DataFrames.